# ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses during attempt to recognize audio

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm trying to run a following code to recognize an audio file. The code is just a compilation from different official examples. But it doesn't work.

```
import os
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import io

def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='ru-RU')

    response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
    for result in response.results:
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

audio_folder_path = 'data_wav'
all_audios = os.listdir(audio_folder_path)

file_name = os.path.join(audio_folder_path, all_audios[0])

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("google_aut.json")

transcribe_file(file_name)
```

I use Anaconda 4.7.12 for Python 3.7 under Windows 10, google-cloud-speech v 1.2.0, google-auth v 1.6.3

The error I get every time is

> _Rendezvous                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py
>   in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
>        56         try:
>   ---> 57             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
>        58         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py
>   in **call**(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials,
>   wait_for_ready, compression)
>       564                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
>   --> 565         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
>       566
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py
>   in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
>       466     else:
>   --> 467         raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
>       468
>
> _Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
>           status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
>           details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
>           debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1569838382.864000000","description":"Failed to pick
>   subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3818,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1569838382.863000000","description":"failed
>   to connect to all
>   addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":395,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>   >
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 transcribe_file(file_name)
>
> in transcribe_file(speech_file)
>        20
>        21     # [START speech_python_migration_sync_response]
>   ---> 22     response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
>        23     # [END speech_python_migration_sync_request]
>        24     # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py
>   in long_running_recognize(self, config, audio, retry, timeout,
>   metadata)
>       339         )
>       340         operation = self._inner_api_calls["long_running_recognize"](
>   --> 341             request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
>       342         )
>       343         return google.api_core.operation.from_gapic(
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       141             kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
>       142
>   --> 143         return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       144
>       145
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py
>   in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       271                 sleep_generator,
>       272                 self._deadline,
>   --> 273                 on_error=on_error,
>       274             )
>       275
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py
>   in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline,
>   on_error)
>       180     for sleep in sleep_generator:
>       181         try:
>   --> 182             return target()
>       183
>       184         # pylint: disable=broad-except
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py
>   in func_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs)
>       212             """Wrapped function that adds timeout."""
>       213             kwargs["timeout"] = next(timeouts)
>   --> 214             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       215
>       216         return func_with_timeout
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py
>   in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
>        57             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
>        58         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
>   ---> 59             six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
>        60
>        61     return error_remapped_callable
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in
>   raise_from(value, from_value)

ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you give any details about your networking, e.g. any proxies that might cause problems? Maybe there is a firewall? The error indicates that some network connections might be blocked.

Comment: Hello, since this question was opened a long time ago, I was wondering if you managed to solve the issue. The syntax and the modules used by the API have changed since then and you would need to update your code. I have been able to run this snippet of code after changing it a little bit and I'm not getting a ServiceUnavailable exception. Could you tell me if you are still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I've got the same issue but I only get the 503 every now and then. It's weired. Concerning Toni's answer: The firewall has been adjusted such that it should cause the issue. Also I only use a single instance of session client for multiple requests.

Answer (score 2):

This could be failing due to the credentials. Let's try few things:

- Ensure that your service account key is correct, you should have something like this:

  > from google.oauth2 import service_account
  >
  > credentials = service_account.Credentials. from_service_account_file('service_account_key.json')
  >
  > speech = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

  OR

  > speech = speech_v1.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)
- Use a Scope:

  > credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  >   credentials_json,
  >   scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

  More info [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/docs/user-guide.rst#service-account-private-key-files).
- In this [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/118#issuecomment-477879931) was solve by using a single instance of a session client object for multiple requests.
- This could be either a network issue as Dustin said. More info here [503 Service Unavailable](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/503-service-unavailable)

Please let us know if you manage to solve this error.