# gcp cloud function - export asset inventory - 503 failed to connect to all addresses;

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**code**

```py
import base64
from google.cloud import asset_v1

def export_assets(event, context):
    # create client
    client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()
    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {} to {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp, context.resource["name"]))
    
    # bq partition spec
    # PARTITION_KEY_UNSPECIFIED = 0
    # READ_TIME = 1
    # REQUEST_TIME = 2
    partition_spec = asset_v1.PartitionSpec()
    partition_spec.partition_key = 1
    
    # init request
    output_config = asset_v1.OutputConfig()
    output_config.bigquery_destination.dataset = "projects/ss-org-logging-project/datasets/cloud_assets_inventory"
    output_config.bigquery_destination.table = "gcp_assets"
    output_config.bigquery_destination.force = True
    output_config.bigquery_destination.partition_spec = partition_spec
    
    request = asset_v1.ExportAssetsRequest(
        parent="projects/ss-org-logging-project",
        content_type = "RESOURCE",
        asset_types = [
            ".*",
        ],
        output_config = output_config,
    )
    
    # make request
    operation = client.export_assets(request=request)
    
    msg_body = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print('Exporting: {}'.format(msg_body))
    response = operation.result()
    
    # handle response
    print(response)
```

This function works without issue if I am running from my laptop. however, when I try to run as cloud function, I am getting following error.

**Error: 503 failed to connect to all addresses;**

**StackTracke**

```
textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 171, in view_func
    function(data, context)
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 35, in export_assets
    operation = client.export_assets(request=request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/asset_v1/services/asset_service/client.py", line 552, in export_assets
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:199.36.153.5:443: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown"
timestamp: "2023-04-12T22:16:57.882769Z"
trace: "projects/ss-org-logging-project/traces/74e7f89a39b98e225737f5006e7ba76b"
}
```

Comment: This could be due to credential issue, Have you checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234341/18265570)? If this is not helpful, can you share your `asset_v1` function?

Comment: yes, and service account associated with cloud function has all the required permission.

Comment: can you share your `asset_v1` function?